# Packer error - sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Tags: automation, terraform, vmware, packer, esxi

I'm been learning how to use Packer this week on my home lab where I have an ESXi 7 host.

I'm simply trying to deploy a Ubuntu 18.04 VM however at the end of the build I get this error in the packer console:

`sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`

This is what I have done.

[Build.json](https://pastebin.com/iqE3bivH)

[Preseed.cfg](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/G0nz0uk/22afe85abc8a1b008602f79b381ea262/raw/ef166effdbdc12b6dc00e40fe5e194181a6b06d4/preseed1.cfg)

[variables.json](https://pastebin.com/1uYznTHN)

Command I run:

`sudo packer build -var-file=variables.json build.json`

In ESXi I see the VM build and complete and reboot and it gets an IP and I get a SSH prompt briefly before Packer deletes the VM after I see the above message.

This is the full error:

```
==> Ubuntu-18.04: Connecting to VNC over websocket...
==> Ubuntu-18.04: Waiting 10s for boot...
==> Ubuntu-18.04: Typing the boot command over VNC...
==> Ubuntu-18.04: Waiting for SSH to become available...
==> Ubuntu-18.04: Connected to SSH!
==> Ubuntu-18.04: Provisioning with shell script: /tmp/packer-shell382031289
==> Ubuntu-18.04: sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
==> Ubuntu-18.04: Provisioning step had errors: Running the cleanup provisioner, if present...
==> Ubuntu-18.04: Stopping virtual machine...
==> Ubuntu-18.04: Destroying virtual machine...
Build 'Ubuntu-18.04' errored after 8 minutes 21 seconds: Script exited with non-zero exit status: 1.Allowed exit codes are: [0]

==> Wait completed after 8 minutes 21 seconds

==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
--> Ubuntu-18.04: Script exited with non-zero exit status: 1.Allowed exit codes are: [0]

==> Builds finished but no artifacts were created.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell `sudo` to read from stdin like this:

```
echo 'password' | sudo -S echo "I am groot"
```

This way your `sudo` command should work.